# Why is CVXPy or DMCP returning a "NoneType" when simple constraints are added?

Tags: python, cvxpy

I recently ran into an interesting package/paper called dmcp (disciplined multi-convex programming). You can find a [link to the repo here](https://github.com/cvxgrp/dmcp/tree/8c3f51055f41436d8974fc1dd831da3a4ae870b1) and a [link to the paper here](http://stanford.edu/~boyd/papers/dmcp.html).

I wanted to use this to solve for equilibria in a model I have been studying in my research (the problem is actually convex, but I've been struggling to get it into DCP form so I figured this would be nice to have as a back up).

We have proved that equilibria always exist and I have been testing the code below on a toy example that I have solved by hand, but for some reason DMCP fails after a few iterations since one of the CVX variable.value is becoming a NoneType (I think).

After looking through the DMCP repo's code, I believe that the error is happening somewhere when they use CVXPy but I don't know enough to figure out whether the error is in DMCP or in CVXPy.

The code I want to get working has parameters:

```
num_agents = 2
num_goods = 2
adjacency_matrix = np.eye(2)
endowment = np.eye(2)
utilities = np.abs(np.eye(2)-1)
resale = np.ones(num_agents)
```

Variables:

```
prices = cp.Variable((num_agents,num_goods), nonneg=True)
consumption = cp.Variable((num_agents*num_agents,num_goods), nonneg=True)
resale = cp.Variable((num_agents*num_agents,num_goods), nonneg=True)
sum_x_ij = cp.Variable((num_agents,num_goods), nonneg=True)
sum_x_ji = cp.Variable((num_agents,num_goods), nonneg=True)
sum_y_ij = cp.Variable((num_agents,num_goods), nonneg=True)
sum_y_ji = cp.Variable((num_agents,num_goods), nonneg=True)
```

Initial values:

```
prices.value = np.random.uniform(low=.1,high=1.1,size=(num_agents,num_goods))
consumption.value = np.ones((num_agents*num_agents,num_goods))
resale.value = np.ones((num_agents*num_agents,num_goods))
```

A helper function:

```
def map_to_idx(agent,neighbor):
    return (agent*num_agents)+neighbor
```

Objective:

```
obj = 0#cp.sum(cp.multiply(utilities[:,:-1],sum_x_ij)) #+ cp.sum(cp.sum(cp.multiply(prices,sum_y_ij),axis=1))
for agent in range(num_agents):
    if utilities[agent,-1] != 1:
        obj += cp.pnorm(cp.multiply(cp.power(utilities[agent,:-1],1.0/utilities[agent,-1]),sum_x_ij[agent,:]),utilities[agent,-1])
    else:
        obj += utilities[agent,:-1]*sum_x_ij[agent,:]
    obj += prices[agent,:]*sum_y_ij[agent,:]
    for neighbor in range(num_agents):
        obj -= prices[neighbor,:]*resale[map_to_idx(agent,neighbor),:]
```

Constraints:

```
constraints = [prices >= 0.1, consumption >= 0, resale >= 0, sum_x_ij >= 0, sum_x_ji >= 0, sum_y_ij >= 0, sum_y_ji >= 0]
for agent in range(num_agents):
    constraints += [sum_x_ji[agent,:] + sum_y_ji[agent,:] == endowments[agent,:] + sum_y_ij[agent,:]]
    constraints += [cp.sum(sum_y_ij[agent,:]) <= resale_vect[agent]]
    lhs_budget_const = 0
    rhs_budget_const = prices[agent,:]*endowments[agent,:] + prices[agent,:]*sum_y_ij[agent,:]
    lhs_sum_xij = 0
    lhs_sum_yij = 0
    lhs_sum_xji = 0
    lhs_sum_yji = 0
    for neighbor in range(num_agents):
        lhs_budget_const += prices[neighbor,:]*consumption[map_to_idx(agent,neighbor),:]
        rhs_budget_const -= prices[neighbor,:]*resale[map_to_idx(agent,neighbor),:]
        if adjacency_matrix[agent,neighbor] == 0:
            constraints += [consumption[map_to_idx(agent,neighbor),:] == 0]
            constraints += [resale[map_to_idx(agent,neighbor),:] == 0]
        lhs_sum_xij += consumption[map_to_idx(agent,neighbor),:]
        lhs_sum_yij += resale[map_to_idx(agent,neighbor),:]
        lhs_sum_xji += consumption[map_to_idx(neighbor,agent),:]
        lhs_sum_yji += resale[map_to_idx(neighbor,agent),:]
    constraints += [lhs_budget_const == rhs_budget_const]
    constraints += [lhs_sum_xij == sum_x_ij[agent,:]]
    constraints += [lhs_sum_xji == sum_x_ji[agent,:]]
    constraints += [lhs_sum_yij == sum_y_ij[agent,:]]
    constraints += [lhs_sum_yji == sum_y_ji[agent,:]]
    constraints += [resale[map_to_idx(agent,agent),:] == 0]
constraints += [cp.sum(prices) == 1]
constraints += [cp.sum(consumption,axis=0) == cp.sum(endowments,axis=0)]
```

and finally:

```
prob = cp.Problem(cp.Maximize(obj), constraints)

print()
print("minimal sets:", dmcp.find_minimal_sets(prob))
print("problem is DMCP:", dmcp.is_dmcp(prob))
print()
result = prob.solve(method='bcd',max_iter = 100)
print(result)
print()
print("p = " + str(prices.value))
print("x = " + str(sum_x_ij.value))
print("y = " + str(sum_y_ij.value))
```

I know that this program has a solution. When I comment out the part of the objective where I am multiplying prices with sum_y_ij and resale, then I things run smoothly. When that is present in the objective I get the following output/errors:

```
Defining variables

Setting some initial guesses

Defining objective

Defining constraints


minimal sets: [[0], [1, 2, 5]]
problem is DMCP: True

max abs slack = 11.257764306622317 mu = 0.005 original objective value = 41.569236735359254 fixed objective value = 20.693015614921645 status= optimal
max abs slack = 21.155476427136296 mu = 0.005 original objective value = 81.25842921844962 fixed objective value = 60.55171440353868 status= optimal
max abs slack = 30.996381672274627 mu = 0.0075 original objective value = 120.77145211345528 fixed objective value = 99.41459375605088 status= optimal
max abs slack = 40.85265643546646 mu = 0.0075 original objective value = 160.97795623707566 fixed objective value = 138.83652995015788 status= optimal
max abs slack = 50.630481600263245 mu = 0.01125 original objective value = 200.88955474035853 fixed objective value = 177.10923936689406 status= optimal
max abs slack = 200.65501019663174 mu = 0.01125 original objective value = 442.07817550005626 fixed objective value = 319.96444147471675 status= optimal
max abs slack = 388.4237602479294 mu = 0.016875 original objective value = 671.3475469742531 fixed objective value = 540.2441656255529 status= optimal
max abs slack = 53335.2974424018 mu = 0.016875 original objective value = 54331.04746214825 fixed objective value = 35106.94351475132 status= optimal_inaccurate
max abs slack = 215936.17724686957 mu = 0.0253125 original objective value = 219254.45219690344 fixed objective value = 40873.564352143076 status= optimal_inaccurate
max abs slack = 27527746.923883904 mu = 0.0253125 original objective value = 23405815.216764793 fixed objective value = 7009847.781686075 status= optimal_inaccurate
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "driver.py", line 64, in <module>
    solv.find_multi_convex_equilibrium(num_agents, num_goods, adjacency_matrix, endowments, utilities, resale_vect, initial_guess=None, verbose=True)
  File "/home/gabe/Graphical_Econs_with_Resale/Jain_Convex_Program/solver.py", line 123, in find_multi_convex_equilibrium
    result = prob.solve(method='bcd',max_iter = 100)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/cvxpy/problems/problem.py", line 289, in solve
    return solve_func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/dmcp-1.0.0-py3.5.egg/dmcp/bcd.py", line 72, in bcd
    result = _bcd(prob, fix_sets, max_iter, solver, mu, rho, mu_max, ep, lambd, linearize, proximal)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/dmcp-1.0.0-py3.5.egg/dmcp/bcd.py", line 119, in _bcd
    max_slack = np.max([np.max(np.abs(var.value)) for var in var_slack])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/dmcp-1.0.0-py3.5.egg/dmcp/bcd.py", line 119, in <listcomp>
    max_slack = np.max([np.max(np.abs(var.value)) for var in var_slack])
TypeError: bad operand type for abs(): 'NoneType'
```

This error even happens if I even include a single prices[0,0]*resale[0,0] in the objective.

Any advice would be super helpful! Thank you!

Comment: The NoneType means that an intermediate solve failed. You may find it helpful to use the MOSEK solver, which is free for academic use. It's very reliable. You can specify the solver for the intermediate convex problems by adding the keyword ``solver=cp.MOSEK`` to the solve call.

Comment: Even Mosek is failing too. I get:
"cvxpy.error.SolverError: Solver 'MOSEK' failed. Try another solver, or solve with verbose=True for more information."

after a few iterations.